# appendChild to animate divs showing only the top div

Tags: javascript

I thought I could use `appendChild` to simulate an animation.  All the divs in a container are hidden except for the first-child.  Here is my code so far, I am not sure why it stops after displaying the second div.

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/dFzA7/

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div>One</div>
  <div>Two</div>
  <div>Three</div>
  <div>Four</div>
  <div>Five</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container div {
  display: none;
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 100px;
  padding: 40px 0;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container div:first-child {
  display: block;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function animateIt () {
  var container = document.querySelector('.container');
  var box = document.querySelector('.container div');

  container.appendChild(box);

};

setInterval( animateIt(), 1000 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
setInterval( animateIt, 1000 );
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I realized as soon as I posted this that i needed to make the `setInterval( animateIt(), 1000 );` look like this:  `setInterval( animateIt, 1000 );`

Here's the working JS:

```
function animateIt () {
  var container = document.querySelector('.container');
  var box = document.querySelector('.container div');

  container.appendChild(box);

};

setInterval( animateIt, 1000 );
```

Comment: Yeah, posting at Stackoverflow nearly always yields the right answer.